# Transferring Blender Toon Shading to Roblox

Tags: modeling, uv, export, texture-baking, toon-shading

I have been trying to transfer my Blender Toon Shader into Roblox, so I can get an effect like this

[Target Goal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGoKMy_8oSI)

But when I tried baking it, it didn't work like this.

Is there any way to achieve such an effect in Roblox studio like this video?
(Gif below, if you didn't want to watch the video).

[image: Image Ref]

Comment: Still looking for help on this particular topic